# Difference between variable and pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am starting to learn C++. I couldnt find proper explanation for few of my questions.

So, from my understanding, a variable is a construct in C++ which holds a value. A pointer is a construct which can store memory address.

So, here are my questions:

1. Can a variable be even called pointer since it points to a memory location? except that unlike pointers, they just point to a fixed location.
2. If the answer is yes to the question above, does that mean are variables' value retrieval done like pointers internally? (using indirection(*) and unary(&) operator?
3. Why do we need to define data types to pointers? At the end, it just points to a location and it can retrieve the value at the location. Is it useful to cast the retrieved bytes from memory?
4. From this [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_operators.htm) definition, pointers are initialized like this: `int  *ptr;`. What does this mean? The website says indirection(*) operator is used to retrieve value from address. What does this operator mean in declaration?

Comment: To understand stuff better you may want to have a look at the assembly code generated. Try using [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/).

Comment: Pointers are used to manipulate with the memory location of the variable, not directly from assignment of variable at every point. You can take an example of Reference variables. You could just change both parametric & main value through it (means the value of variable will also be changed if you do that).

Comment: Pointers are also variables. int variable, int pointer variable; float variable, float pointer variable... Variable contains values, pointer variables contains value addresses.

Comment: check this out, long video but a really good one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iChalAKXffs

Answer (score 3):

> Difference between variable and pointer in c++

A variable is a name that denotes an object or a reference. Colloquially, the word *variable* also applies to the object that it names. A variable always has some type.

Pointer is a category of types.

> 1. Can a variable be even called pointer

Variable and pointer are separate concepts. One is not superset of the other.

They are somewhat similar in abstract sense in that variables can be considered to be a form of compile time indirection.

> 3. Why do we need to define data types to pointers? ...

Because pointers allow indirection. Indirection makes many things possible including data structures such as linked list and search tree, as well as object oriented runtime polymorphism in general.

> At the end, it just points to a location and it can retrieve the value at the location.

Indeed. And the ability to retrieve a value from a pointed location is immensely powerful thing to be able to do.

> 4. ... pointers are initialized like this: `int  *ptr;`. What does this mean? The website says indirection(*) operator is used to retrieve value from address. What does this operator mean in declaration?

`*` is also the multiplication operator. So shouldn't you also be asking, what does the multiplication operator do here?

The answer is that in a type name, `*` is neither the indirection operator nor the multiplication operator. Type names do not have any operators at all. Compound types can have `*` in their name, and the symbol denotes a pointer type. For example, `T*` is a pointer to `T`.

`int  *ptr;` is declaration of a variable whose name is `ptr` and type is `int*` i.e. pointer to `int`.

Comment: Pointer is a category of types. Can you explain what does it mean? I am just starting in CS from non CS background. Sorry if the question is too trivial.

Comment: @Ajay There are many different types. Some types are pointers, other types are not pointers. `int` is a type that is not a pointer. `int*` is a type that is a pointer.

Comment: Here is an additional explanation for the question 3: `Why do we need to define data types to pointers?` -  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-c-examples/